# How can I skip loop for first and last element of array and set them to constant value?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, linq, for-loop

I would like the loop to start from the second element and to end before the last one.
So that I can set the first and last one to constant value.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    Console.Write($"A[{i},{j}] = ");
    tab[i, j] = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ simply:

```
var result = yourArray.Skip(1).SkipLast(1).Prepend(theConstValue)
                      .Append(theConstValue).ToArray();
```

The [`Prepend`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.prepend?view=netcore-3.1), *Adds a value to the beginning of the sequence.*
The [`Append`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.append?view=netcore-3.1), *Appends a value to the end of the sequence.*

Comment: This is .NET Core isn't it?

Comment: @TimSchmelter They are available since .NET Framework 4.7.1, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.prepend?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: @SalahAkbari: Nice, didn't know

Answer (score 1):

Why don't do something like that?

```
for (int i = 1; i < n - 1; i++)
{
  //your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let the loop start at element 1 and end it one earlier